# Ionic cordova build Android failed

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, npm

I need to build an Android App with Ionic Cordova, but there is a problem that I'm not able to solve, hoping for some advice.

My ionic info is as follows:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.4.6
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.10.0-alpha.b34c24dc
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.10.0-alpha.b34c24dc
```

Global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.9.1
npm  : 4.1.2 
OS   : macOS Sierra
```

Use `sudo ionic cordova build android` and there's an error to show:

```
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION:  
    11.+
    ANDROID_HOME=/Users/neolee/Library/Android/sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 
    reached waiting for exclusive access to file: 
    /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip
        at 
    org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Error: /Users/neolee/IonicSpace/ionic-welcome/platforms/android/gradlew: 
    Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 
    reached waiting for exclusive access to file: 
    /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip
        at 
    org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

And I give `/var/root/.gradle` the `sudo chmod -R 777 ...`, but not working.

Can anybody tell me why, and How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you have when run: `$ ls -la /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip` ?

Comment: When I run `ls -la /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2‌​dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-‌​3.3-all.zip`, show this: `Permission denied`; And When I run `sudo ls -la /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2‌​dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-‌​3.3-all.zip` show this: `/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: well, try to change owner of `.gradle` folder: `sudo chown -r your_user:staff path_to/.gradle`

Comment: ok, I try this: `sudo chown -R neolee /var/root/.gradle`, And run `sudo ionic cordova build android`, but the error still exist... `Timeout of 120000 
        reached waiting for exclusive access to file: 
        /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip
`

Comment: Tks, tks, Maxim Shoustin,  I solved it by change my Ionic project file's ownership to current user , Tks agian!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on Windows) and I solved this by giving access permissions directly to the folder.